# AdMob ads not showing in the ads banner

Tags: android, admob

i want to diplay two admob banners, one interacial and an other one in the bottom. 
the interacial one is working great, but for tho other banner, it does only display the banner with no ads.
im working only with codes and there is no xml file and with cordova plugin.

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity{
private AdView adView;
private AdRequest adRequest;
private InterstitialAd interstialAd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml    

adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-123");
adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); 
super.loadUrl(launchUrl);

((LinearLayout) appView.getParent()).addView(adView);
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

interstialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
interstialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-123");
interstialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAdClosed();
    }

    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Call displayInterstitial() function
        displayInterstitial();
    }
});
interstialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
displayInterstitial();
super.onPause();
}

public void displayInterstitial() {
// If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
if (interstialAd.isLoaded()) {
    interstialAd.show();
} else {
    interstialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}}}
```

whats the probleme  ?and thank you for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that both Views share the same AdRequest object, I really think you should create a new one for each View.

```
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
interstialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Comment: unfortunately  i still have the same issue

Comment: You should really check the logcat to see what's going on ;)

Comment: there is no error in the logcat. this is why i dont know what to do

Comment: Some times the ad service does not have an ad ready to be displayed (see documentation) could this be the case?

Comment: no its not cos im using the same id as the ineracial. somthing is blocking that adview i dont know whats it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your llogcat. It will contain details of the ad loading and display. It will tell you you what is happening and why you are not seeing an ad being displayed.

Also, do **NOT** display your interstitial ad from `onAdLoaded()`. It provides a terrible user expereience and will probaboly get your Admob account banned.

Comment: what to use instead of onAdLoaded() ?

Comment: You should display the interstitial at a natural break point in your app. Eg for a game between levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same ad-unit for interstitials and banners.  It sounds like you made an ad-unit for interstitials in your AdMob front end.  Make another ad-unit for banners and use that ad-unit ID for your banner requests instead.